# Batch script to look for a variable in a file and read its value to a variable

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for a batch script to search for a variable in a file and read its value.
Example:
My text file has lines as

```
VERSION=6.0.196.0
CS_VERSION=6.0
```

I want my batch script to find the variable `VERSION` and read its value (`6.0.196.0`) to a variable `PVERSION` in my batch script and then value of `CS_VERSION` (`6.0`) to another variable `DVERSION`.

How can i do this?
searched for some similar questions but they are giving me outputs as:

```
PVERSION==VERSION=6.0.196.0
DVERSION==CS_VERSION=6.0.
```

I just need output as

```
PVERSION=6.0.196.0
DVERSION=6.0.
```

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it an plain text file or a binary?

Comment: Yes Jeb its a plain text file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way (read each line, delimiting on `=` and capturing the lhs/rhs to `%%A` & `%%B`);

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol= tokens=1,2 delims==," %%A in (the.file) do (
    if "%%A"=="VERSION" (
        set version=%%B
    ) else if "%%A"=="CS_VERSION" (
        set cs_version=%%B
    )
)

echo VERSION is %version%
echo CS_VERSION is %cs_version%
```

---

Test;

```
@echo off
@(
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
echo 4
echo 5
echo 6
echo 7
echo 8
echo 9
echo 10
echo 11
echo 12
echo 13
echo 14
echo 15
echo 16
echo 17
echo VERSION=6.0.196.0
echo CS_VERSION=6.0
) > the.file

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol= tokens=1,2 delims==, skip=17" %%A in (the.file) do (
    if "%%A"=="VERSION" (
        set version=%%B
    ) else if "%%A"=="CS_VERSION" (
        set cs_version=%%B
    )
)

echo VERSION is %version%
echo CS_VERSION is %cs_version%
```

Comment: It works for me if I put `VERSION=6.0.196.0` and `CS_VERSION=6.0` on lines in a text file, sure the path is correct?

Comment: Yes the path is correct and its a text. There are some 24 lines in text file. The VERSION and CS_VERSION are in 18th and 19th line. So i used skip=17 in for loop.

Comment: Updated with example that creates `the.file` then scans it and it seems ok to me, can you show your file?

Comment: If I have only two lines in my file, is there any way that i can read only the first line and catch the variable skipping the second line?

Comment: not sure what you mean, if you only want to capture the 1st occurrence; dont assign if you have already done so; `if not defined version set version=%%B`

Comment: MY FILE CONTAINS license related information upto the 17th line which is simply a text. Then the VERSION=6.0.196.o and CS_VERSION=6.0 followed by the other text information.

Comment: Alex help me such that how can i read only the VERSION on 18th line and exclude CS_VERSION on 19th line. Guess this would help me.

Comment: @Bala Does the sample of Alex works for you (with his sample file)?

Comment: @jeb Alex's sample file is not working for me. copied the 19 lines to a text file and called it in a test.bat file with the script as provided. but i see empty output.

Comment: @Alex, found the mistake in my code there was no space between delims==, and skip=17.... Thats the issue troubled me without output... Now im getting the output.... Thanks guys and sorry for troubling you....